# Write something in href without affecting the path of html file

Tags: javascript, html, css, web

i'm new in Web Development and creating a website.
There i get data from the Movie Database API, especially the id.
Now i want if you click on a movie, another page should load and the Details are displayed.
Currently i am passing the ID this way:

> MovieDetails.html#{id}

Is there a better way to pass the id other than localstorage?
Is there a way to do something like this `MovieDetails.html-{id}`

Comment: Use query string

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use query parameters as well. `#` gives instructions to browser to go to element passed after `#`

You can use query parameters with `JavaScript` like:

```
function getQueryVariable(variable)
{
       var query = window.location.search.substring(1);
       var vars = query.split("&");
       for (var i=0;i<vars.length;i++) {
               var pair = vars[i].split("=");
               if(pair[0] == variable){return pair[1];}
       }
       return(false);
}
```

Reference: https://css-tricks.com/snippets/javascript/get-url-variables/

Get full information from reference.

First thing, you should understand what each line does in `JavaScript`

Comment: Personally I would use https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/URL/searchParams, your reference is quite old :)